# Fetch Audio for IVR

Tags: twilio, ivr

Twilio has advised that they do not provide any out of the box fetch audio for IVRs when they are retrieving information from externals systems an it is taking longer than a second or two.  Has anyone implemented this on Twilio (studio)?  If so, where did you source the audio?  Google searches haven't yielded any results

Searching various providers for "fetch" and "comfort" audio but have not found any results

Comment: This post on [Twilio Flow change handle long HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77424291/twilio-flow-change-handle-long-http-requests/77428096?noredirect=1#comment136574573_77428096) may give you some ideas.